# Cron expression as an aggregator release strategy

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'd like to put an `aggregator` in my chain that aggregates all the incoming messages (String) and release the aggregated message (String) in particular moments, which I'd like to define using a "cron expression" (like those used in pollers)

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you'd like to release your messages from the aggregator only by cron expression, I recommend you to take a look to the [`MessageGroupStoreReaper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper), which is responsible to initiate `forceComplete` operation on the aggregator. As you see from docs the `cron` stuff must be done on the `<task:scheduled>`.

The `messageStore` for the `MessageGroupStoreReaper` must be that one from the `<aggregator>` and isn't shared with other components.

The aggregator config may look like this:

```
<aggregator message-store="messageStore"
   release-strategy-expression="false"
   expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
   send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"/>
```

This is recommended over implementing a `ReleaseStrategy` in this case because a release strategy is only consulted when a new message arrives, making time-based release strategies impossible.